# Principal ideals in the ring of power series in $z$ with an infinite radius of convergence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, ideals

Let $A$ be the subring of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ of power series with an infinite radius of convergence. I want to show the following characterization of its principal ideals: Let $f,g\in A$. Then
$$f\in (g)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad\forall a\in\mathbb{C},  n\in\mathbb{N};\; (z-a)^n\mid g\Rightarrow (z-a)^n\mid f.$$
The direction $``\Longrightarrow"$ is clear (It works as in the polinomial case). But I do not know how to prove the other direction.

**Obs:** For $``\Longleftarrow"$ it is clear that if $a$ is zero of $f$, then $a$ is zero of $g$. Also, I know that the zeros of $f\in A$ form a discrete set in the complex plane. Could it be useful?

Thanks!

Comment: Immediate by [Weierstrass factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)

Comment: @user10354138 You meant immediate from the Cauchy integral formula. Iff $\forall a\in \Bbb{C},v_a(f)\ge v_a(g)$ then $f/g$ is analytic on the whole complex plane so that its Taylor series has infinite radius of convergence and $f\in (g)$.